# Derivation of Einstein's relation in Drift Diffusion model for Semiconductors

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I'm currently reading *Semiconductor Devices: Basic Principles* by Jasprit Singh. In this book he gives a derivation of the Einstein relation for the Drift Diffusion model of semiconductors, supposing equilibrim conditions (all current densities are zero) and Boltzmann statistics, that is, e.g. for the electron concentration:

\begin{equation}
n=n_i exp\left(-\frac{E_{Fi}-E_F}{k_BT}\right),
\end{equation}

Now comes the fishy part, because in the book he writes:

\begin{equation}
\vec{\nabla}n=\frac{n}{k_BT} \left(-\vec{\nabla}E_{Fi}+\vec{\nabla}E_F\right),
\end{equation}

which means that the gradient of the intrinsic carrier density is zero (according to the product rule, its derivative also has to be taken into account, which is not, thus it is zero). To this I see no reason, especially not in the case of an externally applied electric field. Can somebody explain this to me, please?

Side question: he also uses the relation:

\begin{equation}
\vec{E} = \frac{1}{e}\vec{\nabla}E_{Fi}
\end{equation}

Where does this come from?

Comment: What does the _intrinsic_ carrier concentration depend on? Or, perhaps, you could clarify how you think it should depend on an externally applied electric field.

Comment: @JonCuster Problem is, that it's not specified in the book, but as far as I can tell, it is automatically taken to be spatially independent, to which I see no reason.

Comment: If the material is spatially uniform (the base material, not any dopants), why would the intrinsic carrier concentration vary? Perhaps you need to go back and understand what the intrinsic carrier concentration actually means.

Comment: @JonCuster I'm really far from knowing everything about semiconductors, but even in the case of a spatially uniform material, if there is an electric field, the charge distribution should be uneven, so that an equilibrium is possible, shouldn't it? Supposing no dopants this uneven carrier density is the intrinsic density, since it comes from the base material. (It is not 100% clear in the derivation whether it is external, but I guess it should be the sum of the internal and external field, since it is included in the drift current density.)

Comment: The point is, the intrinsic carrier concentration is dependent only on the material. It comes from a detailed balance consideration of the equilibrium between holes and electrons and their recombination. It does not vary with doping, applied field, or anything else besides the base material itself. At all times, the materials strives to achieve $np = n_{i}^{2}$ by generating or recombining charge carriers. Doping changes $n$ or $p$, but not $n_{i}$.

Comment: @JonCuster Ahha, I didn't know that the intrinsic carrier concentration does not depend on the field either. Thanks. Btw can you answer the second part of my question, too?

Comment: Well, it is called 'intrinsic' for a reason... As for the second part - how does the electric field relate to a spatially varying potential - for simplicity think of a capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of books on this topic.

Instead of focusing on:

\begin{equation}
n=n_i \exp\left(-\frac{E_{Fi}-E_F}{k_BT}\right),
\end{equation}

I would focus on a derivation using:

\begin{equation}
n=N_C \exp\left(\frac{E_{F}-E_C}{k_BT}\right),
\end{equation}

where $N_C$ is the electron density of states and $E_C$ is the conduction band edge.  In equilibrium, $E_F$ is constant and $E_C$ depends on the electrostatic potential, and electron affinity.  The $N_C$ is a material property that can be considered constant for a homogeneous material.

The definition of $n_i$ would require the consideration of holes and the mass action law.  I consider it a mistake that the authors you refer to would involve the intrinsic carrier density.  If you now include holes:

\begin{equation}
p=N_V \exp\left(\frac{E_{V}-E_F}{k_BT}\right),
\end{equation}

and define:

\begin{equation}
n p=n_i^2,
\end{equation}

and recognize the $E_F$ is the same for both $n$ and $p$ at equilibrium, you will get the definitions for $n_i$ and $E_{Fi}$.  If you consider the case where the energy gap is constant

\begin{equation}
E_G=E_C-E_V,
\end{equation}

and that:
\begin{equation}
E_C=\chi -q\psi,
\end{equation}

where $\chi$ is the electron affinity, and $\psi$ is the electrostatic potential, you will see that $n_i$ is constant.

An excellent reference would be "Device Electronics for Integrated Circuits", by Muller and Kamins.

An excellent online reference is http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter2/ch2_7.htm

Comment: If you could add into your answer also the connection between the intrinsic Fermi level and the electric field, I'd be grateful. Iguess it is just simply shifted by the electric potential, but why the intrinsic Fermi level? I would understand that the Fermi level (shifted by doping) gets a slope that of the electrostatic potential, than, after equilibration, the difference in carrier concentration makes the Fermi flat again. But why does the intrinsic level remain shifted?